# Salesforce1: looks like stylesheet has gone!

Tags: salesforce1-app

The last couple of days, for no apparent reason, when I look at Salesforce1 on the iPad, some pages seem to have lost the CSS.  This is happening for me, but not for all users.  Anyone has any idea what's happening?

[image: SFDC 1 ScreenShot]

Comment: Is this the iPad app or the browser? Have you tried both? And is this a custom VF page? Maybe if you delete the app and reinstall it it will rectify itself. Very strange.

Comment: strange indeed... Do you have any inline visualforce pages or other special things on those pages where you have this issue?

Comment: This is simply a standard Account page layout, but this is happening with any page where I am viewing a record, or viewing a list view.  I'll try deleting and re-installing.

Comment: And it's the iPad only, works fine with /one/one.app.

Answer (score 1):

Delete and re-install fixed it.  But still very strange.